# How to set Payment Term of Bill on Bill.com from API

Tags: php, api

[image]

Hi. I want to set the payment terms from API but no found the doc that explain that here the doc http://developer.bill.com/api-documentation/api/bill.
Is the api not support that?? Or am I missing in the doc?? Can you help me.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i send a question about that into their developer (developerprogram@hq.bill.com).
they said if payment terms are not available on their API system.
here are their answer : 
Payment Terms are not available via the API.
I apologize for any inconvenience this may cause, but you are in full control of dates when creating bills so you could set up payment term logic in your code when generating dates.